# Class 'MyApp\Thread' not found

Tags: php, namespaces, ratchet

I'm trying Ratchet with pthreads and run into my not understanding of namespaces. I have added new file to my application:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;

class Test1 extends Thread
{
    public function run()
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
            sleep(10);
            echo 1 . date(' H:i:s') . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

but I mess up something with namespaces because I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\Thread' not found in /home/idea/CLI/src/MyApp/Test1.php on line 4

Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\Thread' not found in /home/idea/CLI/src/MyApp/Test1.php on line 4
```

Why PHP can't find Thread class? It is working fine outside of Ratchet.

Comment: can you include your folder structure.

Comment: But Thread class is from pthreads, it is not inside my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've moved your current namespace to `MyApp` and, therefore, need to reference the `Thread` class with its fully qualified name: `\Thread`.

[Read more on namespace resolution here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)